# MySql Event doesn't recur?

Tags: mysql

I recently created an event that will clear one of my tables from the database once a day, every day, at 8:20am. I created the event at around 8:15am and it seemed to work for that day but the following days nothing was happening.

**SHOW EVENTS**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: awi_dev6
                Name: e_daily
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: RECURRING
          Execute at: NULL
      Interval value: 1
      Interval field: DAY
              Starts: 2018-08-03 08:20:38
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: cp850
collation_connection: cp850_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

**COMMAND TO CREATE EVENT**

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '0:05' HOUR_MINUTE
COMMENT 'Clears out sessions every day.'
DO
  DELETE FROM awi_dev6.sessions;
```

Does anyone know why this event isn't recurring?

Comment: Is your event_scheduler running correctly? I believe it should show up if you run SHOW PROCESSLIST\G and you can see what the variable shows by running SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler'; See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Comment: Yup, I see the event scheduler and looks similar to what is expected from the example in your link.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change it to be like

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '0:05' MINUTE
COMMENT 'Clears out sessions every day.'
DO
  DELETE FROM awi_dev6.sessions;
```

Comment: Ok, just ran your updated post and it worked as expected. I guess I just have to wait until tomorrow to see if it empties the table on schedule.